# Can I change from a 26 x1.95 tire to a 26 x 1.75 tire on the same rim?

Tags: tire

I want to put 26 x 1.75 tires on my mountain bike.  It currently has 26 x 1.95 tires on it.  Will the rims hold the somewhat smaller tires?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @BRoberts. Good to see you've taken the [tour], so you understand how things work here. We think you'll find the answer to your question in the suggested duplicate. Your question will now serve to help others find the same info.

Answer (score 0):

All roads lead to sheldon on this one... here is another question that discusses this issue in converse (how wide in this case).  In reality, the OP did not provide any ISO sizing data for the 2 tires nor the rim, so can't really answer. (but tentatively, yes, it should work fine)  [How wide of tires can I run on a Victory Vision road bicycle?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/how-wide-of-tires-can-i-run-on-a-victory-vision-road-bicycle/16666#16666)

Comment: 26-inch tires with decimal widths (almost) all use the same rim diameter, so there should be no difficulty with the swap.  26-inch with fractional widths are a different matter.